# Creation of users and see list of the user created by a specific roles like?

Tags: users

I have three kind of role business manager,gen manager and handler.
Business manager can create an account for gen manager and activation will done automatically.

My requirement is that How can Business managers see the list of created gen manager  when business manager will login with its account in site.

gen manager can create an account for handler and activation will done automatically.

My requirement is that How can gen managers see the list of created handler  when gen manager will login with its account in site.

Comment: Please review my edited version of your question (trying to make it fit the rules of this site). Feel free to further correct/enhance where needed. Also, maybe you want to better explain (via an extra edit) what exactly you mean with that "see the list of users": do you mean (a) creating an appropriate view or (b) have some menu option (or URL) that can be used to get access to such list or (c) something else?

Comment: You did not specify a Drupal version, but if you are using D7, you might have a look at the [subuser module](https://www.drupal.org/project/subuser): _This module allows users to be given the permission to create subusers. The subusers may then be automatically assigned a role or roles. The parent of the subusers then has the ability to manager the users they have created._

Comment: The problem with this question is not how the text is formatted, or the used grammar. The problem is that is too broad as it is. Editing the question to change format or fix the grammar doesn't make it less broad.